# How can I make multiple jwplayer audio players inside a jquery-ui accordion render and work correctly?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jwplayer, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to improve and update the look of a page that has multiple jwplayers (audio only). The "original" page works fine - all the audio players render correctly and are usable (see http://www.pera.state.nm.us/meetingaudio.html).

But I'm trying to put the audio players in a jquery-ui accordion, and all is not right; the first player inside the accordion div is rendered and works correctly, but all subsequent players inside that same accordion div are rendered incorrectly and will not play. The play button appears to be rendered underneath the progress bar. Here is some sample code that illustrates the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/jquery-ui-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/jwplayer6/jwplayer.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/pera-custom/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $(".accordion").accordion({
        heightStyle: "content"
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="accordion">
    <span class="accHead">February 28, 2013</span>
    <div class="accContent">
      <div id="Board20130228" class="audioPlayer" style="float: left;"></div>
      <div style="float: right;"><span class="smallNote">Length:<br />1:29:55</span></div>
    </div>

    <span class="accHead">January 31, 2013</span>
    <div class="accContent">
      <div class="audioPlayer" id="Board20130131" style="float: left;"></div>
      <div style="float: right;"><span class="smallNote">Length:<br />1:49:53</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer('Board20130228').setup({
      'file': 'http://www.pera.state.nm.us/audio/BoardMeetingFeb28_2013.mp3',
      'controlbar': 'bottom',
      'width': '420',
      'height': '40',
      'provider': 'audio',
      'primary': 'html5'
    });

    jwplayer('Board20130131').setup({
      'file': 'http://www.pera.state.nm.us/audio/BoardMeetingJan31_2013.mp3',
      'controlbar': 'bottom',
      'width': '420',
      'height': '40',
      'provider': 'audio',
      'primary': 'html5'
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So you can easily see this in (in)action, I've put together a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/timbck2/y4RSS/.

I'm using the latest version (as of today, 4/8/2013) of jwplayer: 6.3242.

Can anyone help me?

UPDATE: As Ethan pointed out, the players all work fine in Firefox v.20. But they are broken in Chrome (v.26), IE (v.10), and Safari (Mac). Here is an image showing what I see in all non-Firefox browsers for all players after the first one in an accordion:

[image: broken jwplayer]
The play button appears to be hidden behind the progress bar, and is not clickable.

Comment: Do you have a non jsfiddle example of the issue? Just a blank test page.

Comment: I'll put something up tomorrow when I get to work and post here.

Comment: I just checked this in FF20, Win7, all of the players work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to ultimately be a clash between the jQuery/jQuery-ui libraries and the jwplayer library. The workaround is to make the players render as flash first and fallback to html5 (instead of the other way around, as I had it coded).